# No funciona MatSort en MatTable - Angular 9

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema, `MatSort` no funciona en mi `MatTable`, he intentando cambiar varias cosas (como por ejemplo traer primero la data del `getMainList`), pero ninguna me resulta, espero puedan apoyarme.

Dejo el código:

#### HTML:

```html
<m-portlet [options]="{headLarge: true}">
    <ng-container mPortletHeadTitle>
        <div class="m-portlet__head-title">
            <h3 class="m-portlet__head-text"> Lista de Documentos de Medida </h3>
        </div>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container mPortletHeadTools>
        <button type="button" mat-raised-button style="background-color: #FF8D00; color: white" matTooltip="Nuevo"  (click)="AddEditMedicionVehiculo(0)">
            <fa name="plus-circle" inverse='true'></fa>&nbsp;&nbsp;Nuevo Punto
        </button>
    </ng-container>     
    
    <ng-container mPortletBody>
        <div class="m-form">
            <div class="m-form__filtration">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <form [formGroup]="formBusqueda">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- <div class="col-sm-2 m--margin-bottom-10-mobile">
                                    <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid">
                                        <mat-select formControlName="Equipo" placeholder="Vehiculo">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of Equipos" [value]="item.Id"> {{item.Placa}} </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div> -->
                                
                                <div class="col-sm-2 m--margin-bottom-10-mobile">
                                    <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid">
                                        <mat-select formControlName="Equipo" placeholder="Vehiculo" matInput>
                                            <mat-option>
                                                <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="filterEquipos" [placeholderLabel]="'Buscar...'" [noEntriesFoundLabel]="'No se encontró resultado'"></ngx-mat-select-search>
                                            </mat-option>
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filtered_Equipos | async" [value]="item.Id">
                                                {{item.Placa}}
                                            </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>

                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-sm-3 m--margin-bottom-10-mobile">
                                    <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid">
                                        <mat-select formControlName="TipoPunto" placeholder="TipoPunto">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of TipoPuntos" [value]="item.Valor"> {{item.Nombre}} </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-3 m--margin-bottom-10-mobile">
                                    <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid">
                                        <mat-select formControlName="UnidadMedida" placeholder="UnidadMedida">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of UnidadesMedida" [value]="item.UnidadMedida"> {{item.Nombre}} </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-sm-1 m--margin-bottom-10-mobile">
                                    <button type="button" mat-mini-fab color="bg-green" (click)="getMainList()" matTooltip="Buscar">
                                        <fa name="search" inverse='true'></fa>
                                    </button>
                                </div>

                                <!-- <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <mat-form-field class="col-md-12 search-form-field">
                                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey" placeholder="Buscar en todos los campos" autocomplete="off" 
                                            class="mat-form-field mat-form-field-fluid" (keyup)="searchInsideTable()">
                                        <mat-hint align="start">
                                            <strong>Buscar en todos los campos</strong>
                                        </mat-hint>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div> -->

                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid">
                                        <input matInput  formControlName="searchKey" placeholder="Buscar en todos los campos" autocomplete="off" 
                                            class="mat-form-field mat-form-field-fluid" (keyup)="searchInsideTable()">
                                        <mat-hint align="start">
                                            <strong>Buscar en todos los campos</strong>
                                        </mat-hint>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mat-table__wrapper">
            <mat-table [dataSource]="listData" matSort perfectScrollbar>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="N">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="head_back">N°</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson,let i = index"> {{ i + 1}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="PuntoMedida">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="head_back">PuntoMedida</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.PuntoMedidaDisplay}}</mat-cell>
                </ng-container> -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Equipo">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="head_back">Equipo</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.EquipoDisplay}}</mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="UnidadMedida">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="head_back">UnidadMedida</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.UnidadMedidaDisplay}}</mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="TipoPunto">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="head_back">TipoPunto</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.TipoPuntoDisplay}}</mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Descripcion">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="head_back">Descripcion</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.DescripcionDisplay}}</mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Activo">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="head_back">Activo</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">
                        <span class="m-badge m-badge--{{ lesson.ActivoDisplay == 'SI' ? 'success': 'danger' }} m-badge--wide">{{ lesson.ActivoDisplay }}</span>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="FechaMedida">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="head_back">Fecha Medida</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.FechaMedidaDisplay | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' }}</mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Operaciones">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="head_back">Acciones</mat-header-cell>
                    
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">
                        <button  style="color: #00A09D !important" mat-icon-button color="primary" matTooltip="Editar Medicion" (click)="AddEditMedicionVehiculo(lesson.PuntoMedidaDisplay)">
                            <mat-icon>create</mat-icon>
                        </button>&nbsp;
                        
                        <button *ngIf="lesson.ActivoDisplay == 'SI' " mat-icon-button style="color: #F2242E !important" type="button" data-toggle="modal" (click)="enabledisabled(lesson.PuntoMedidaDisplay,false)" matTooltip="Dar de baja">
                            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                        </button>&nbsp;
                        
                        <button *ngIf="lesson.ActivoDisplay == 'NO' " mat-icon-button style="color: #b7343d !important" type="button" (click)="enabledisabled(lesson.PuntoMedidaDisplay,true)" matTooltip="Dar de Alta">
                            <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                
                <ng-container matColumnDef="loading">
                    <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="10">
                        <mat-spinner [diameter]="20"></mat-spinner>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Loading data...
                    </mat-footer-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="noData">
                    <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="10"> No se encontraron registros. </mat-footer-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>

                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" class="hoverable_row"></mat-row>
                <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['loading']" [ngClass]="{'hide': load_data}"></mat-footer-row>
                <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noData']" [ngClass]="{'hide': no_data}"></mat-footer-row>
            </mat-table>
        </div>
        <div class="mat-table__bottom">
            <mat-paginator #MatPaginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 50, 100, 200]" [pageSize]="10" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
        </div>

    </ng-container>
</m-portlet>
```

#### Component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort, MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { ToastrManager } from 'ng6-toastr-notifications';
import { SubheaderService } from '../../../../../config/_core/services/subheader.service';
import { MantenimientoService } from '../../_core/services/mantenimiento.service';
import * as Excel from 'exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js';
import { UtilsMantenimientoService } from '../../_core/utils/utils-mantenimiento.service';
import { Observable, ReplaySubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";
import { UnidadMedida } from '../../../MMModuleApp/_core/models/unidad-medida.model';
import { database } from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'm-documentos-medida-vehiculo',
  templateUrl: './documentos-medida-vehiculo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./documentos-medida-vehiculo.component.scss']
})
export class DocumentosMedidaVehiculoComponent implements OnInit {

  Estados:Array<any>=[]; 
  TipoPuntos:Array<any>=[]; 
  UnidadesMedida: Array<any>=[]; 
  TipoOrdenes:Array<any>=[]; 
  SubTipos:Array<any>=[];
  Bases:Array<any>=[]; 
  Equipos:Array<any>=[]; 
  arrayList:Array<any>=[];
  
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['N','Equipo','UnidadMedida','TipoPunto','Descripcion','Activo','FechaMedida','Operaciones'];

  listData: MatTableDataSource<any>; 
  @ViewChild(MatSort) MatSort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
   
  formBusqueda: FormGroup;
  
  posible_Equipos = null;
  filterEquipos: FormControl = new FormControl();
  filtered_Equipos: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject<any>();
  array_Equipos: any = [];
  
  protected _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();
  
  searchBan: boolean = false;
  searchKey: string;
  load_data = false;
  no_data = true;


  constructor(
    private subheaderService: SubheaderService,
    public mantenimientoservice:MantenimientoService,
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public toastr: ToastrManager,
    private utilsService: UtilsMantenimientoService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.subheaderService.setTitle('Mantenimiento');
    this.subheaderService.setBreadcrumbs([ { title: 'Mantenimiento - Documentos de Medida Vehículo'} ]);
  
    this.createFormBusqueda();
    this.getEquipos_combo(); 
    this.getMainList();
    

  }

  createFormBusqueda(){
    this.formBusqueda = this._formBuilder.group({
      Equipo: [0,Validators.required],
      TipoPunto: [0,Validators.required],
      UnidadMedida: [0, Validators.required] , 
      searchKey: [null],
    });
    
    this.mantenimientoservice.getTipoPunto().subscribe( (data: any) => { 
        this.TipoPuntos = data;
        this.TipoPuntos.unshift({ Valor: 0, Nombre: 'TODOS' })
        this.formBusqueda.controls.TipoPunto.setValue(0);
      }
    ); 

    this.mantenimientoservice.getUnidadesMedida().subscribe( (data: any) => { 
      
      this.UnidadesMedida = data; 
      this.UnidadesMedida.unshift({ UnidadMedida: 0, Nombre: 'TODOS' })
      this.formBusqueda.controls.UnidadMedida.setValue(0);
    }
      ); 
  }

  getEquipos_combo() {
        this.mantenimientoservice.getEquipos().subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
                this.array_Equipos = data;
                this.filtered_Equipos.next(this.array_Equipos.slice());
                this.filterEquipos.valueChanges
                    .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
                    .subscribe(() => {
                        this.filtrar_Equipos();
                    });
                this.formBusqueda.controls.Equipo.setValue(
                    Number(this.posible_Equipos)
                );
            },
            (errorServicio) => {
                console.log(errorServicio);
            }
        );
    }

  filtrar_Equipos() {
    if (this.array_Equipos.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        let search = this.filterEquipos.value;
        if (!search) {
            this.filtered_Equipos.next(this.array_Equipos.slice());
            return;
        } else {
            search = search.toLowerCase();
        }
        this.filtered_Equipos.next(
            this.array_Equipos.filter(
                item => item.Placa.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1
            )
        );
  }

  changeModulo(eve, item) {
    if (eve.source.selected) {
      this.mantenimientoservice.getSubTipoOrden(item).subscribe( (data: any) => {
        this.SubTipos = data;
        this.SubTipos.unshift({ SubTipoOrden: 0, Descripcion: 'TODOS' })
        this.formBusqueda.controls.SubTipo.setValue(0);
        // this.form.controls.SubTipo.setValue(1);
      }
    );
    }
  }

  getMainList(){ 
       
    const _controls = this.formBusqueda.controls;
      if (this.formBusqueda.invalid) {
        Object.keys(_controls).forEach(controlName => _controls[controlName].markAsTouched() );

        this.toastr.warningToastr('Ingrese los campos obligatorios.', 'Advertencia!', {
          toastTimeout: 2000,
          showCloseButton: true,
          animate: 'fade',
          progressBar: true
        });
      }else{
        this.searchBan = false;
        this.load_data = false;
        this.no_data = true;
        let Equipo = _controls['Equipo'].value;
        let TipoPunto = _controls['TipoPunto'].value;
        let UnidadMedida = _controls['UnidadMedida'].value; 

        this.mantenimientoservice.getDocumentosMedidaVehiculo(Equipo,TipoPunto,UnidadMedida).subscribe(
          (data: any) => {
            this.arrayList = data;
            this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(data);
            this.listData.sort = this.MatSort;
            this.listData.paginator = this.paginator;
            this.no_data = data.length>0? true:false;
            this.load_data = true;
            // this.loading=false;
          }
        )
      }
    
  }

  AddEditMedicionVehiculo(Id){ 
    console.log("IDDD",Id);
    {const dialogRef = this.utilsService.addEditMedicionVehiculoDialog(Id==0?'Registrar medición vehículo':'Editar medición vehículo', Id);
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(res => {
      debugger
            if (res) { this.getMainList(); return; }
      else { return; }
    });}
  }

  enabledisabled(id: number,estado: boolean){ 
    
    console.log("nuevo estado para:",id,estado);
    let accion = estado==true?'Activar':'Desactivar';
    let ejecutando = estado==true?'Activando':'Desactivando';
    let data: any = {
      title :  accion +' Documento de Medicion Vehículo',
      description : '¿Esta seguro de '+accion+' Documento de Medicion del vehículo?',
      waitDescription : ejecutando+' ...',
      labelYes : accion
    };
    
    data.callback = (data): Observable<any> => {
      return new Observable(obs => {
        this.mantenimientoservice.DocumentoMedicionVehiculoEnabledDisabled(id,estado).subscribe((response: any) => { 
          console.log("response",response);
            if (response==1) {
              this.toastr.successToastr(response.Message, 'Éxito!', {
                toastTimeout: 2000,
                showCloseButton: true,
                animate: 'fade',
                progressBar: true
              });
              obs.next(true);
            } else {
              this.toastr.errorToastr(response.Message, 'Error!', {
                toastTimeout: 2000,
                showCloseButton: true,
                animate: 'fade',
                progressBar: true
              });
              obs.next(false);
            }
          }, (error) => {
            this.toastr.errorToastr(error.error.Message, 'Error!', {
              toastTimeout: 2000,
              showCloseButton: true,
              animate: 'fade',
              progressBar: true
            });
            obs.next(false);
          });
      });
    }
  
    const dialogRef = this.utilsService.confirmCallback(data);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(res => { console.log("respuesta de dialog"+res);
      if (!res) {
        return;
      } else {
        this.getMainList();
      }
    });
  }

  formatNumber(n: number){
    console.log(n)
    var val = n.toFixed(3);
    var parts = val.toString().split(".");
    var num = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");

    return num;
  }
  
  searchInsideTable() {

    var searchKey=this.formBusqueda.controls['searchKey'].value;
    this.listData.filter = searchKey.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### SOLUCIONADO

Lo he solucionado, el problema era tener mal llamado al `matColumnDef`; debe ser el mismo nombre cómo se llama desde el backend, lo que está entre paréntesis `{{ ... }}`

##### Antes:

```js
 displayedColumns: string[] = ['N','Equipo','UnidadMedida','TipoPunto',
'Descripcion','Activo','FechaMedida','Operaciones'];
```

```html
<!-- ... -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="Equipo">
 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header 
 class="head_back">Equipo</mat-header-cell>
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.EquipoDisplay}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<!-- ... -->
```

##### Después:

```js
displayedColumns: string[] = ['N','EquipoDisplay','UnidadMedidaDisplay',
'TipoPuntoDisplay','DescripcionDisplay','ActivoDisplay',
'FechaMedidaDisplay','Operaciones'];
```

```html
<!-- ... -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="EquipoDisplay">
 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header 
 class="head_back">Equipo</mat-header-cell>
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.EquipoDisplay}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<!-- ... -->
```